# multiple database deletes, only one registered with a cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've written a cloud function which listens for deletes from firebase realtime database.  It works great if there is just one deletion -- the console shows that item as having been removed.

However, if there are multiple deletes at the same time in my realtime database, my cloud function only gets triggered for one of these deletions!  What am I doing wrong?

*Here is my scenario: I open two browser tabs on the same site.  Each time I connect to my web app in each tab, I create a realtime database entry and a reference via `push`. Then I close both tabs by closing the browser window, which calls `onDelete` on my references which triggers the removal of that reference on the database via `remove` -- and I can confirm both are deleted from the database.  However, only one of the deletes is registered in my cloud function.*

**The Cloud Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onPresenceRemove = functions.database.ref('/status/app').onDelete( (snapshot, context) => {
    const original = snapshot.val();
    console.error( 'snapshot', original, snapshot, context );
    return true;
});
```

**The js Realtime Database Code**

```
presenceDoc = firebase.database().ref( '/status/app' );

firebase.database().ref( '.info/connected' ).on( 'value', function( snapshot ) {
  if ( snapshot.val() === true ) {

    presenceRef = presenceDoc.push( userId );

    presenceRef.onDisconnect().remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that your callback registering a deletion is being passed a "set" of database changes and it is up to your code to iterate over them?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you expect the triggered function to be passed for each one of these deletes? You're expecting four different snapshots?  Is `appId` the same value in each browser window?

Comment: @Kolban yes, I expected a set of changes, but inspection of the snapshot and context objects don't show multiple items.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the posting for clarity.  When I close just one tab, my cloud function gets the pushed `reference: userId`.  When I close a window with many tabs, I expected the cloud function to be called multiple times, or an enumeration to be passed to the cloud function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Cloud Function is set to trigger on:

```
functions.database.ref('/status/app').onDelete
```

So when `/status/app` gets deleted (i.e. when its last child node gets removed), your function will get triggered with a snapshot of the last data under `/status/app` before the deletion.

Your client code seems to be adding new child nodes under `/status/app`, with a structure like:

```
status
  app
    pushId1: userId1
    pushId2: userId1
    pushId3: userId2
```

Your Cloud Function only gets triggered when app of `/status/app` is removed, so when the last child node is deleted.

You probably want to trigger your Cloud Function when each child gets deleted. For that you trigger should be one level lower in the tree:

```
functions.database.ref('/status/app/{pushId}').onDelete(...
```